# TensorFlow Keras: Bad metrics and no improvement on classification. Am I missing something?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

First of all, I'm relatively new to machine learning and neural networks. I'm currently trying to build a neural network that can perform predictions over a heart diseases dataset. Here's what a single tuple of my dataset looks like:

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data/processed/cleveland_processed.data')
>>> df.iloc[0]
age          63.0
sex           1.0
cp            1.0
trestbps    145.0
...           ...
thal          6.0
num           0.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

All of the fields refer to some different kinds of data, in my particular case, that last field (`num`) is the value I want my network to predict. It ranges from 0 to 4, with 0 being the total absence of any disease or anomaly, and 4 being a probably very dangerous cardiac situation. 5 possible levels of diagnostic.

Then I splitted my data into both training and testing (`x_train`, `x_test`, and so on) I used Scikit-learn's `MinMaxScaler` for the task, mapping every value from zero to one.

And finally, I defined my model. I used the `Sequential` model. Now, here comes my problem. as I've mentioned, I wanted to predict some value ranging from 0 to 4 discretely. I went through the [TensorFlow Keras basic classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) guide, since it provides an example of classifying data into labels (0 to 9), similar to what I am trying here.

```py
>>> model = tf.keras.Sequential([
...     layers.Input(13),
...     layers.Dense(13, activation='relu'),
...     layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')
... ])
>>> model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
...               loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
...               metrics=['accuracy'])
>>> model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=2, epochs=100)
```

The training process in the guide seems to go pretty well, however, it wasn't my case. Loss values start at ~3.x and ends up fixed at 1.6094 around the 30th epoch. Same with accuracy, starting at ~0.4x and not going higher than 0.5472.

I've tried changing my approach to this, replacing `num` by 5 new fields (`lv0`, `lv1`, `lv2`... `lv5`) and filling the tuple with a 1 on the respective level of condition, and zero for all the rest of levels (something like `[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` for a level 1 condition as my `y_train`/`y_test`) and replacing activation functions with `sigmoid`, alongside changing the `loss` function to `binary_crossentropy` (since that approach worked for a similar model of mine). No improvements.

I also tried staying with `relu` as activation function, but replacing the optimizer with `rmsprop` and the loss function to be `mse`, and again, no improvements.

Am I missing something? Is it something with my data? Or maybe scaling was the problem? I've tried other stuff that is not worth mentioning, since it was like giving blind steps. If anyone has an idea on what might be wrong with my model or my approach, I'll be happy to hear it!

Comment: the output layer should have a softmax activation, not ReLU, why are you using ReLU there?

Comment: I'll give it a try! I used ReLU just as an attempt to see if anything changed, since the example on the TensorFlow guide I mentioned didn't have any activation function on the output layer.

Comment: So, after applying softmax on the output layer, [here's the result](https://imgur.com/a/nXU06Gt). I increased the epochs to 200, and although accuracy did increased, and loss started decreasing, when I add validation data from x_test and y_test, predictions aren't lookig as good as they should.